# ¿ Pueden explicarme diferencias entre eloquent y \DB:: en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, orm

Recién empiezo con Laravel y tengo diversos problemas... el caso es que estaba utilizando los \DB::

Como esto por ejemplo que ya conoceréis:

```
$macUsuario=\DB::table($this->tablaMac)
                ->join($this->tablaUsuario, $this->tablaUsuario . '.Correo', '=', $this->tablaMac . '.Id_usuario')
                ->select('Direccion_mac', 'Descripcion', 'Correo', 'Nombre', 'Apellidos', 'Fecha')
                ->where('Departamento', '=', $departamento)
                ->get();
```

Y me han dicho que use los ORM de eloquent "o algo así" , he visto este vídeo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJmSZVQIbXs

Resulta que en el minuto 21.04 hace :

```
$estudiante = Estudiante::find(1);
```

Si he entendido bien va a buscar en la tabla Estudiante la PrimaryKey "1", no ?

El caso es que no veo diferencia con usar

```
$persona=\DB::table($this->Estudiante)
         ->select("Nombre","Apellido")
         ->where('pk','=',1)
         ->get();
```

La de usar menos línea de código, pero lo veo mejor porque así no te traes todos los campos de la BBDD , solo los que necesitas...

También si es posible, me dijeran más vídeos o documentación para novatos para entenderlo mejor, en youTube solo están los vídeos de Duilio Palacios y no me entero nada de nada.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con

```
$estudiante = Estudiante::select('Nombre','Apellido')->find(1);
```

Solamante selecionas las columnas Nombre y Apellido.

Eloquent devuelve una collecion de objetos y sus relaciones (importante), de tal forma que para obtener, por ejemplo, las asignaturas de un estudiante no tendrás que hacer un join ya que Eloquent te lo da hecho:

```
$clases=Estudiante->clases;
```

La alternativa sería algo similar al código que has puesto de ejemplo:

```
$macUsuario=\DB::table($this->tablaMac)
                ->join($this->tablaUsuario, $this->tablaUsuario . '.Correo', '=', $this->tablaMac . '.Id_usuario')
                ->select('Direccion_mac', 'Descripcion', 'Correo', 'Nombre', 'Apellidos', 'Fecha')
                ->where('Departamento', '=', $departamento)
                ->get();
```

Una vez definido el modelo y las relaciones no tienes que volver a ocuparte de las consultas.

Y como recomendación de videos y/o documentación, mi recomendación es que tomes un curso de Duilio Palacios por un lado y eches un vistazo a la documentación de Laravel (ahora en español) [Documentación Laravel en español](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/installation). Cuando he querido aprender algo nuevo de Laravel, han sido mis fuentes.

Comment: Unas preguntillas... Tengo que hacer las migretions ?    min 4,50   
                                            
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISWY2A8GH4E 

O puedo tener las tablas en mysql?

Comment: Obviamente las migrations son opcionales pero muy cómodas ya que permiten crear/modificar la base de datos en cualquier entorno. Al final lo que hacen es crear las tablas y las relaciones; si, además, añades seeders ya tienes datos para probar. Insisto: curso con Duilio